# Why does sending data between activities not work?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently using Kotlin. I am trying to change the colour of a box in main activity by going to another activity that is the colour setting activity. My code returns no errors but not working. I tried reading different result on this page but none answering my question. Thank u for your help.

mainactivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button_box = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_box)

        button_box.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, boxColor::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                val returnColor = data!!.getStringExtra("colorName")

                val boxColorChoice = when (returnColor) {
                    "green" -> R.drawable.box_green
                    "grey" -> R.drawable.box_grey
                    "lblue" -> R.drawable.box_lblue
                    "purple" -> R.drawable.box_purple
                    "red" -> R.drawable.box_red
                    "white" -> R.drawable.box_white
                    "yellow" -> R.drawable.box_yellow
                    else -> R.drawable.box_white
                }
                button_box.setBackgroundResource(boxColorChoice)
            }
        }
```

here is boxcolor.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_box_color)

        val green = findViewById<Button>(R.id.green_box)
        val red = findViewById<Button>(R.id.red_box)
        val white = findViewById<Button>(R.id.white_box)
        val yellow = findViewById<Button>(R.id.yellow_box)
        val grey = findViewById<Button>(R.id.grey_box)
        val lblue = findViewById<Button>(R.id.lblue_box)

        green.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra("colorName", "green")
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            finish()
        }

     (and the same onclicklistener for all the other colours)
```

also I know this is small problem but thank you very much for helping. I am 14 year old boy from rajasthan and I want to be a programmer and learning

Comment: in file `mainactivity.kt` in your click event, you are starting activity like: `startActivity(intent)`. If you expect new activity to return a result, you should start it like: `startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE);`. check this tutorial: http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/pass-data-between-android-activities/

Answer (score 1):

you need to use startActivityForResult your code must change to these :

mainactivity.kt

```
...
val mRequestCode = 101  //ADD THIS LINE
...
button_box.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, boxColor::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, mRequestCode) //ADD THIS LINE
        }
...
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

            if (resultCode == mRequestCode) { //CHANGE THIS LINE
                ...
            }
        }
```

and in your   boxcolor.kt:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_box_color)
        val mRequestCode = 101  //ADD THIS LINE

        ...

        green.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra("colorName", "green")
            setResult(mRequestCode, intent)  //CHANGE THIS LINE
            finish()
        }

     (and the same onclicklistener for all the other colours)
```

**Note that don't use Activity.RESULT_OK as requestCode**

Answer (score 0):

Please use **Request Code** and **startActivityForResult**

Example:

> **private val RC = 101**
>
> **val intent = Intent(this, boxColor::class.java)**
>
> **startActivityForResult(intent, RC)**